# Cannot mount Galaxy S7 with simple-mtpfs (with S4 it used to work fine)

Tags: connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, mount, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I would like to mount my Samsung Galaxy **S7 (SM-G930F)** to an folder using **simple-mtpfs** and I cannot do it as I used to (on previous Fedora and older Galaxy S4).

If I simply plug S7 to my computer, I can browse it using Nautilius, but I cannot access it in terminal as ordinary folder, what is exactly what I want to achieve.

**Every time I plug S7 I check twice that it works in MTP mode, so that isn't the problem.**

In the past, I simply plugged the phone and typed something as:

```
$ simple-mtpfs /home/adam/S7
```

Now, I can perform it and even my phone ask me to confirm MTP choice, but the catalogue S7 is still empty.

I also tried to mount it as root or ordinary user and by device number, but with no result.

```
# simple-mtpfs --list-devices
1: SamsungGalaxy models (MTP)

$ simple-mtpfs --device 1 /home/adam/S7
# simple-mtpfs --device 1 /media/s7

$ simple-mtpfs /dev/libmtp-3-1 /home/adam/s7
# simple-mtpfs /dev/libmtp-3-1 /media/s7
```

I even tried to do it by udev rules:

```
# dmesg | tail
[16821.258485] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[16821.258487] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[16821.258489] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????
[16827.556099] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 29
[16830.383366] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
[16830.548882] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[16830.548887] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[16830.548903] usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[16830.548905] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[16830.548907] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????

# touch /etc/udev/rules.d/10-phone.rules
```

Content of */etc/udev/rules.d/10-phone.rules* is set to:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}="6860", SYMLINK="S7"
```

After reloading rules I have */dev/S7* and I've tried to mount it:

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules

# ls -l /dev/S7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 10-20 15:03 /dev/S7 -> bus/usb/003/075

# ls -l /dev/libmtp-3-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 10-20 15:03 /dev/libmtp-3-1 -> bus/usb/003/075

# simple-mtpfs /dev/S7 /media/s7
```

**And still without any result. Mounting doesn't give and errors, but the directory where I about to mount is still empty.**

The details about my setup:

```
# uname -r
4.7.7-200.fc24.x86_64

# rpm -qa | grep mtp
simple-mtpfs-0.2-6.fc24.x86_64
libmtp-1.1.11-1.fc24.x86_64
gvfs-mtp-1.28.3-1.fc24.x86_64

# rpm -qa | grep fuse
fuse-libs-2.9.7-1.fc24.x86_64
glusterfs-fuse-3.8.4-1.fc24.x86_64
fuse-2.9.7-1.fc24.x86_64
gvfs-fuse-1.28.3-1.fc24.x86_64
```

Under Windows I can plug the phone and I see its whole content (the same as in Nautilius), but not as ordinary USB Mass Storage (drive with a letter assigned).

I've also tried to enable Developer Options and set the USB Debugging Mode and ... nothing.

**Thank you in advance for your help.**

---

**Extract from system log (Fedora's journalctl) after plugging the phone and typing *simple-mtpfs /media/s7* :**

```
# journalctl -n 53
-- Logs begin at śro 2016-10-19 21:29:20 CEST, end at sob 2016-10-22 09:26:43 CEST. --
paź 22 09:24:31 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
paź 22 09:24:31 PRZEDNICZEK01 PackageKit[1559]: get-updates transaction /384_eccedcee from uid 1000 finished with success after 45ms
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:0
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,011]/'
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,011]/'
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:5e7b19a6b9795726a5c47a99a89757bf', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:24:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:5c7e6bb78b9a6691c3ecea3925b2971d', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: (gnome-shell:1832): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError:  is null
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: ContentTypeDiscoverer<._onContentTypeGuessed/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/autorunManager.js:133
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: _proxyInvoker/asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/Gio.js:86
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:34 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3243): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/18 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:24:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 PackageKit[1559]: get-updates transaction /385_decdbbba from uid 1000 finished with success after 45ms
paź 22 09:26:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: usbfs: process 3385 (simple-mtpfs) did not claim interface 0 before use
paź 22 09:26:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
paź 22 09:26:38 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: usbfs: process 3385 (simple-mtpfs) did not claim interface 0 before use
paź 22 09:26:38 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: usbfs: process 3250 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
paź 22 09:26:40 PRZEDNICZEK01 kernel: usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 98867?????????????
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: PTP: reading event an error 0x02ff occurredDevice 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: LIBMTP ERROR: couldnt parse extension samsung.com/devicestatus:0
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,012]/'
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not find parent node for URI:'mtp://[usb:003,012]/'
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-WARNING **: NOTE: URI theme may be outside scheme expected, for example, expecting 'file://' when given 'http://' prefix.
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:0e6a8582e05ac627e4014d1ca1e6ec87', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 tracker-miner-fs.desktop[2001]: (tracker-miner-fs:2001): Tracker-CRITICAL **: Could not set mount point in database 'urn:nepomuk:datasource:5c7e6bb78b9a6691c3ecea3925b2971d', GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.Tracker1.SparqlError.Internal: UNIQUE constraint 
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 dbus-daemon[1760]: [session uid=1000 pid=1760] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer' requested by ':1.16' (uid=1000 pid=1832 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
paź 22 09:26:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 dbus-daemon[1760]: [session uid=1000 pid=1760] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer'
paź 22 09:26:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: (gnome-shell:1832): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: TypeError:  is null
paź 22 09:26:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: ContentTypeDiscoverer<._onContentTypeGuessed/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/components/autorunManager.js:133
paź 22 09:26:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1832]: _proxyInvoker/asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/Gio.js:86
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_infos_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 gvfsd[1813]: ** (process:3399): WARNING **: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path /org/gtk/vfs/client/enumerator/17 (g-dbus-error-quark, 19)
paź 22 09:26:43 PRZEDNICZEK01 PackageKit[1559]: get-updates transaction /386_acdeddea from uid 1000 finished with success after 48ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `jmtpfs`. The "solution" I found was to unmount/remount the device *after allowing the connection on the phone following the first mount*. This is not elegant, but maybe somebody with a better understanding of how Android handles this aspect of MTP permission can provide a better answer based on this answer (if so, please ping me in the process!).

EDIT: I just tried something else... after plugging in the phone, from the pulldown notifications list selecting the one about "connecting via usb" gives a set of choices; explicitly selecting the MTP option, *then* mounting, works normally.